# Rails has_many/accepts_nested_attributes_for Create confusion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit confused when it comes to one thing and that's creating MULTIPLE "belongs_to" model items in the controller.

Basically, I've seen it where say we have a `Person` model, and that `Person` `has_many` `Addresses` and also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses`

(Let's pretend the Address is just a single text field, and let's say in the form we are going to end up having 3 addresses for a person)

In the "new" controller I will typically see something like:

```
@person = Person.new
3.times { @person.addresses.build }
```

Then in the "create" controller action it'll go through and do the normal create all while accepting all 3 fields (using `fields_for` form) of addresses. via something like:

```
def person_params
 params.require(:booking).permit(:name,:email,:age, :addresses_attributes => [:address])
end
```

And it'll create all 3 addresses just fine. I don't understand how it works. Were building 3 different instances and then somehow rails just "knows" how to associate them?

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare that a Person model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses`, all you are really saying is I want Rails to create getter and setter instance methods on the Person model for addresses (plural).
This is similar to other relationships. For instance, if you declare a has_many :friends relationship on Person, you would be able to call `@person.friends`(the getter) or `@person.friends.create`(the setter).
Heres a visual...

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this is the getter method
  def addresses
    # I can retrieve all of the associated addresses for a particular person
  end

  # this is the setter method
  def addresses_attributes=(attributes)
    # I can take in any number of addresses and assoicate them to a particular person
  end
end
```

When you permit addresses_attributes in the controller

```
params.require(:person).permit(:addresses_attributes => [:address])
```

Think of it like you are allowing the `addresses_attribues` setter method to be called when creating a Person...the setter method takes in the addresses (plural) submitted from the form and associates them with that particular person. But, when you call @person.addresses, you'll notice that it returns an [ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html), which is important to understand.

In the controller, when you say

```
@person = Person.new
3.times { @person.addresses.build }
```

Think of it like creating an empty Person and 3 empty addresses associated with that person, which will only be populated with attributes once the create action is called by submitting the form.

EDIT:

The main benefit of nested attributes (and it's difference from a normal association) is that it allows you to use a single form to create/modify the parent class (in this case, the Person), and at the same time create/modify it's associated attributes (in this case, addresses) through the use of `fields_for`

"I guess the other confusing part is how rails knows that the Person has 3 empty addresses?"

Rails doesn't know right off the bat...which is why you have to explicitly instantiate X amount of empty addresses in the controller. So now when you call `form.fields_for :addresses` there is only X amount of memory to store X amount of addresses.

Comment: So is the setter technically taking an array of arrays (pretending `addresses_attributes` had more than 1 "field" (maybe state and city or something)?

Also you reference `has_many` being able to call `@person.friends` or `@person.friends.create` then how is that different from `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?

I guess the other confusing part is how rails knows that the Person has 3 empty addresses? is there any way I could see the "blank" portions of addresses in console or something?

Thanks though, this has helped.

Comment: Sure you can use byebug to inspect the empty address objects. For example, after you build the 3 address in the new action of the controller, call byebug and use the terminal to inspect what @person.addresses looks like!

Comment: Each addresses_attributes could be passed in as either an array of hashes or a hash of hashes...and so by only permitting :address in this example, if one of the hashes that was passed in looked like this... `{ address: "123 Seasme St", bad_stuff: "something bad" }`, it wouldn't be saved.

Answer (score 1):

`accept_nested_attributes_for :addresses` in your `Person` model defines an attributes writer for the `has_many :addresses` association.

Now when you submit your form to the Rails application, The params might look something similar to this:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>'John', "email"=>'john@domain.com',"age"=>"25"
addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"address"=>"Street 1"}, "1"=>{"address"=>"Street 2"}, "2"=>{"address"=>"Street 2"}}}
```

If you take a close look at the `addresses_attributes` param, it looks similar to a `hash` and each `key` in that `hash` represents an `address` object. That is how Rails will exactly know that it has to create 3 `address` records.

Also if you would like to understand this better, go through this [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

***Updated:***

It is not at  all compulsory to instantiate the addresses in advance in the `new` action with `3.times { @person.addresses.build }`

And hardcoding number of addresses might not be a right way to do it. What if someone wants to store 5 addresses and your application allows just 3?

So probably you can use [Jquery](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) and implement this in a much better way. Or even you could use [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem.

Comment: So the writer can accept an array of parameters in my example case I assume?

Comment: Yes, Even if you `build` just 3 addresses in `new` action but if you manage to pass 10 `addresses` in `addresses_attributes` then all 10 addresses will be created.

Comment: This is a good point. In most circumstances, you will not know the number of nested attributes beforehand and could use the cocoon gem to simplify adding nested attributes to your form dynamically. My answer is, therefore, largely theoretical due to the nature of the question (although I added/left stuff out to make it more understandable from a high level).